# Linux distribution, Rails and an IDE

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, ide, distribution

I have been developing in RoR for the last month. As I am new, I 'd rather use an IDE which helps a lot in code completion. In any case, I use RubyMine. Thing is that for the IDEs to work properly, best practice is to be installed in the development environment itself.

So, I am now going for a development environment: Of course i choose Linux, but here is my question:

Is there any linux distro specifically built for software development? I assume it needs LAMP and a  lightweight graphical environment that supports RubyMine. I can install RVM later.

Answer (score 0):

Any general-purpose Linux distribution will come with a plethora of development tools.  Fedora, Debian, Ubuntu, SuSE, and dozens of others will fit your needs.  Remember: All Linux distributions are developed by, well, developers... and they need development tools, too.

As a general rule, the only distributions that will *not* have development tools for them are special-purpose distros, where those things have been stripped out to save space, or make the installation simpler.

Comment: Thanks Flimzy! My main concern is to leightweight. I am planning to VMware the distribution and from my research I have figured out that _none_ of the distros is working substractively, meaning that every and each one have plenty of tools that a developer doesn't use. 

I incline more to the idea to build a customize distro of my own, but I need a good and reliable minimal distro to build upon. I also found this tool to help out: Remastersys

Comment: Sure, they have them available, but you don't need to install them. Debian comes on multiple _DVDs_ now.  But nobody installs _everything_. In fact, it's _impossible_ to install all of the available packages--some of them conflict with each other!